# I can find my GPU in tensorflow, but everytime I run I will disconnect to the kernel

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, gpu, spyder

[I want to run the CNN model it's called VGG16 in tensorflow, I have followed the
rules to set up GPU into tensorflow and create a new env through the anaconda,
I also tried to reinstalled everything. I couldn't find related error on the google.
Please help me please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2Vhp.png)

```
train_y = np_utils.to_categorical(train_y)
test_y = np_utils.to_categorical(test_y)
train_X = train_X.astype("float32")
test_X = train_X.astype("float32")
vgg = VGG16(input_shape = (60,80,3), include_top=False)
vgg.summary()
type(vgg)
model = Sequential()
for layer in vgg.layers:
    model.add(layer)
model.layers.pop()
for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable = True
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(5, activation= 'softmax')) 
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=15) 
print(history)
```

everything is normal

Comment: Run the code in a terminal, outside jupyter, and it will probably give you a better error message that you can include in your question.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) What's your Spyder version?